# Android element properties point to another element property

Tags: android

There is a way to link an element's property to another element's property through the xml layout?
I want to disable some elements using a check box, I know how to do using the  "onclick" and java code, but i'm looking for something like this :

```
<Button
    android:enabled="@+id/checkBox:checked"
/>
```

Comment: I think, you have to use  android:enabled="@id/checkBox:checked", instead of  android:enabled="@+id/checkBox:checked" . i never tested but   try it.  I've also faced some problems like yours, not exactly but a kind of. and i understood that i've to use @+id only when ever we create new id and use @id while in the reference.

Comment: Well, all the xml looks like this, it was automatically created by the Android Studio, it is not he problem that I'm having atm, but thanks for the tip c:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no integrated way in Android. I guess they left it out due to complexity, it is not a simple management layer. However, there are efforts to implement the MVVM principle, like the one you are searching for. One of them is [bindroid](https://github.com/depoll/bindroid). However, didn't use it nor did my colleagues. You need some boilerplate code, or implement some form of the [ObserverPattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) , like [this](https://andhradroid.wordpress.com/2012/04/05/object-observer-pattern-in-android/).

Answer (score 0):

`Preference` offers a `android:dependency` attribute from XML, but not `Button`.

You'll have to implement this by code, with a simple `onClick()` usage.